# Rendering an image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on an app which has a product page and an image won't render on the website despite the rest of the information on inside the return statement rendered. I have no errors on web dev tools, the app compiled successfully with the following code.

ProductScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProductScreen() {

  const { id } = useParams();
  // const params = useParams();
  // const { id: productId } = params;

  const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === (id));

  if (!product) {
    return <div> Product Not Found </div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>

      <Link to="/">Back To Result</Link>

      <div className="row top">

        <div className="col-2">

          <img className="large" src={product.image} alt={product.name} ></img>

        </div>
```

The Main page did render all the images though.  Not sure how to find the issue especially when there is no error showing.

[screen shot of terminal, web dev tools and the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yocwk.png)

Comment: you can try with `<img className="large" src={require(product.image)} alt={product.name} ></img>`

Comment: Can you `console.log(product.image);` so we can see the image path?

Comment: @coglialoro
 When added the require - this is what I got on console... Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'images/p1.jpg'

Comment: @Tomer Almog
When i console.log(product.image) - I got "images/p1.jpg"

Comment: so check which one of these work: `<img className="large" src="images/p1.jpg" alt={product.name} />`. `<img className="large" src="/images/p1.jpg" alt={product.name} />` `<img className="large" src="./images/p1.jpg" alt={product.name} />` based on where you have the actual image file

Comment: I believe the problem is that the path is not relative to the file they're been used in. What you could do is required them in you data.js files and put the actual image in the `data` rather then the path. Like `import NikeSlimShort from 'images/p1.jpg'` and `const data = { /*omitted*/ image: NikeSlimShirt'`. not sure how good this is performance wise though

Comment: @Tomer Almog <img className="large" src="/images/p1.jpg" alt={product.name} /> - this one render the image...

Answer (score 1):

This is solved thru the suggested solution of @Tomer Almog! Also, thank you @Luigi Remor & @coglialoro for taking the time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the src is right, look at your project directory and see if it is there "../data". If it exists, look in each object from the list and look if the image is forwarding to the right folder.

Comment: I believe so. i have a data.js file that has this and the ProductScreen is accessing from data.js.

Comment: ```const data = {
  products: [
    {
      _id: '1',
      name: 'Nike Slim Shirt',
      categoty: 'Shirts',
      image: 'images/p1.jpg',
      price: 120,
      countInStock: 10,
      brand: 'Nike',
      rating: 4.5,
      numReviews: 10,
      description: 'High quality product',
    },
]}```